# Proving Probability Inequality

Tags: probability

[image]

I'm having trouble deriving this. By the normalization postulate, the author means $P(X)+P(\neg X)=1$ and by the conjunction postulate, the author means Bayes' theorem.

This is all I've got:

$$ P(b|a) = \frac{P(a|b)*P(b)}{P(a)} $$
$$ 1 = \frac{P(a|b)*P(b)}{P(a)} $$
$$ P(a) = P(a|b)*P(b) = P(a,b) $$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're basically done. You have:

$$ 1 = \frac{P(a|b)*P(b)}{P(a)} $$

So: $$ P(a) = P(a|b)*P(b) \leq P(a|b)$$ since $P(b) \leq 1$

Answer (score 0):

If $\Pr\left(b\mid a\right)=1$ then: $$\Pr\left(a\mid b\right)\Pr\left(b\right)=\Pr\left(a,b\right)=\Pr\left(b\mid a\right)\Pr\left(a\right)=\Pr\left(a\right)\geq \Pr\left(a\right)\Pr\left(b\right)$$

or equivalent: $$\left[\Pr\left(a\mid b\right)-\Pr\left(a\right)\right]\Pr\left(b\right)\geq0$$